# QGIS Crashreport is not generating since I updated to 3.22.16

Tags: qgis, debugging

I'm creating plugins for QGIS and one of my biggest problems is to debug a QGIS crash.

When we worked with QGIS 3.10 the stack was saved to "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\QGIS\QGIS3\crashes"

But since our team uses QGIS 3.22.16 there are some users which got no new entries.
I checked the source code but I don't know a lot about C++.
I guess the crashhandler should create the files, but I can't figure out more.

crashhandler:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/0a4796c0c29bba36cb3820282e88e9c1c822f846/src/crashhandler

Does someone know how to activate the crashreports again?